# How is a capacitor in series with a resistor and capacitor in parallel calculated?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, resistors

How do you calculate this circuit?

[image: circuit diagram]

I would like to calculate both the voltage, current and charge progression of those three components seen as one part as well as their individual voltages, currents and charges.

The values given in the circuit diagram are just placeholders but for completeness let us assume the total voltage 10VDC.

I would like to understand the mathematics behind such a calculation and not only know the solution to this specific example.

Thank you in advance

Edit: I want to analyse the circuit assuming the capacitors are initially uncharged. It was pointed out to me that that is a transient analysis.

Comment: Well you are going to get infinities at t = 0 so there's a clue.

Comment: You need to tell us how the voltage source behaves as a function of **time**. Does it supply a dc voltage? Does the voltage change suddenly from one value to another? Does the voltage source provide an ac voltage at a fixed frequency and constant amplitude?

Comment: You are right i forgot that. It's 10 volt dc. I edited the question for clarification too. @ElliotAlderson

Comment: Do you know how much current flows through a capacitor if a constant dc voltage is applied? That's the key to solving this problem.

Comment: If you are talking about this formula I(t)=V_0/R*e^(-t(R*C)) yes i do. I also know how it is applied to 2 caps in series. It's the parallel connection combined with the cap in series that i don't know about. @ElliotAlderson

Comment: No, that's not the formula for a capacitor connected to dc...that's the formula for a capacitor connected to a voltage source where the voltage changes with a step function at t=0.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor#DC_circuits) mentions it as the DC formula @ElliotAlderson

Comment: The wikipedia entry is for a circuit that includes a **switch**. Your circuit has no switch. The switch effectively causes the applied voltage to change with a step function, and this is properly called a "transient analysis" rather than a dc solution.

Comment: I understand. But closing the circuit with the switch is essentially the same thing as hooking the circuit up for the first time right? For a short period afterwards the charge in the caps rises until it (almost) hits 100%. At that point the caps have an infinite resistance and there is (almost) no current. Right? Now what i want to calculate is the short period after closing the switch/hooking the circuit up when current and charge is changing massively. If that is a transient analysis thats what i want to do. I thought this formula is the one to use and i just need the proper way of using it

Comment: @ElliotAlderson i forgot to add your name in the comment above.

Comment: Well. you didn't say anything about "hooking up the circuit for the first time". A DC problem assumes that voltages and currents **never** change.

Comment: The circuit you show is invalid for the case of "hooking up for the first time" if you assume that the capacitors are initially discharged. At the instant of connection the capacitors will have the same voltage across them (0V) but KVL says their total voltage must equal the supply voltage. So, you are missing some important information or some important circuit elements.

Comment: I understand. So my goal is to calculate the voltages etc assuming the capacitors are initially discharged. I guess i was missing the right vocabulary. How would I need to draw the circuit to resemble what i want? With a switch? And now that you know what i want is it possible to do a transient analysis on this circuit? @ElliotAlderson

Comment: @ElliotAlderson ^

Comment: If you assume that the initial voltages across the capacitors are 0V each then the circuit is a nonsense circuit and can not be analyzed. At the instant when the voltage source is connected the capacitor voltages will still be zero, and KVL will be violated around the outer loop.

Comment: What do you mean with "violated"? I could build this circuit in reality and the capacitors would get charged right after connecting the circuit to the voltage source, wouldn't they? @ElliotAlderson

Comment: Yes, in real life you could do that. But the schematic you have presented is not a suitable model for "real life". It is lacking critical elements such as the ESR of the capacitors themselves. **As drawn** the schematic you present and the scenario you describe can not be analyzed using conventional circuit techniques.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson So if i specified an ESR for both of these caps the circuit could be analyzed?

Comment: Yes. You need some resistance in series with the voltage source.

Comment: Thank you so much @ElliotAlderson. You helped me rectify wrong assumptions i somehow came to. I will create a new question with a correct circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it all depends on Kirchoff's Voltage Law. It indicates all voltages sum through a closed loop must equal to zero. So we start dividing voltages to branches. I suggest you to take a look at both Kirchoff's Current Law and Kirchoff's Voltage Law.